# A combinatorics question

Tags: combinatorics

How can one easily see that for $n,k \in \mathbb N_0$:

$\sum_{j=\max(0,k-m)}^{\min(n,k)}\frac{\begin{pmatrix} n \\ j \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} m \\ k-j \end{pmatrix}}{\begin{pmatrix} n+m \\ k \end{pmatrix}}=1$?

Comment: Define "easily"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Write this as 
$$
\sum_{j\ge0} \binom{n}j\binom{m}{k-j}=\binom{n+m}{k}
$$
Then, find a combinatorial interpretation of the above equality. Ask yourself: Why is choosing $j$ things from a set of size $n$, then choosing $k-j$ things from a set of size $m$, for any $j$, the same as choosing $k$ things from a set of size $n+m$?

Note: to make the bounds on $\sum$ simpler, I used the convention $\binom{n}k=0$ when $k>n$ or $k<0$.

Alternatively, consider the below equation
$$
(1+x)^m(1+x)^n=(1+x)^{m+n}
$$
Expanding both sides with the binomial theorem,
$$
\left(\sum_{i=0}^n\binom{n}ix^i\right)\left(\sum_{j=0}^m\binom{m}jx^j\right)
=\sum_{\ell = 0}^{n+m}\binom{n+m}{\ell}x^{\ell}
$$
The coefficient of $x^k$ on both sides of each equation must be equal to each other. The $x^k$ coefficient on the right is $\binom{n+m}k$, and after a some thought, on the left it is $\sum_{j\ge0} \binom{n}j\binom{m}{k-j}$.